# Use accelerometer in landscape mode

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, android-sensors

So I'm pretty new to Android programming and my current project involves moving a picture left and right by tilting. It works fine but I can't figure out how to make the accelerometer useful in landscape mode (forced landscape). I get good results if i hold the phone upright (it remains in landscape) but obviously that doesn't really fulfill my needs. Is there a quick fix for this I can use?

Comment: Do either of these questions help you?    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094279/android-accelerometer-issue    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065632/android-compass-example-does-not-seem-to-work-in-landscape-mode

Comment: OK, so you managed to get it working it portrait mode? Could you post your code?